# How to calculate the moment of inertia of a 2 point mass system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

I have 2 point masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ connected via a massless rigid rod to a center. $m_1$ is at the distance $r_1$ from the center and $m_2$ is at the distance $r_2$ from the center. How would i calculate the moment of inertia of the system?

Comment: Are you looking for the MMOI about the rod center, or the center of mass?  The former is going to be larger than the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the sum of the point mass moments of inertia

$$I=\sum_i m_ir_i^2 =m_1r_1^2+m_2r_2^2+...$$

Comment: This is the MMOI about the rod center, and not the center of mass. Of course the OP wasn't clear where the MMOI should be measured.

Comment: I assume he put the axle at the middle of the rod, because the given distances are "from the center".